# NServiceBus: Custom ISubscriptionStorage implementation with no generic-host

Tags: nservicebus

I am unable to use my custom ISubscriptionStorage implementation when I use something other than the generic host.  I'm not really sure why.  I am getting an exception of "Cannot publish on this endpoint - no subscription storage has been configured. Add either 'MsmqSubscriptionStorage()' or 'DbSubscriptionStorage()' after 'NServiceBus.Configure.With()'."

Only I don't want to use these options because I want to use my custom option.

Here's what I have that's failing:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var bus = Configure.With()
            .CustomConfigurationSource(new UserConfigurationSource()
                .Register(() => new MsmqTransportConfig())
                .Register(() => new UnicastBusConfig()))
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(true)
            .UnicastBus()
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();

        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<StreamSubscriptionStorage>(ComponentCallModelEnum.Singleton);

        Console.WriteLine("This will publish IEvent and EventMessage alternately.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to publish a message.To exit, Ctrl + C");

        bool publishIEvent = true;

        while (Console.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            var eventMessage = publishIEvent ? bus.CreateInstance<IEvent>() : new EventMessage();

            eventMessage.EventId = Guid.NewGuid();
            eventMessage.Time = DateTime.Now.Second > 30 ? (DateTime?)DateTime.Now : null;
            eventMessage.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(99999D);

            bus.Publish(eventMessage);

            Console.WriteLine("Published event.");

            publishIEvent = !publishIEvent;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your custom subscription storage before starting the bus. You can do that by including .RunCustomAction( your code here ) in the fluent initialization.